# content from divs into textarea

Tags: php, javascript, html, copy, textarea

I'd like to transfer text from all div's with specific class to the textarea on the same page.

How can I do that?

for example:

```
< div class="test1" > Example1 < /div >
< div class="test2" > Example2 < /div >
< div class="test1" > Example3 < /div >
< div class="test3" > Example4 < /div >
```

I would like to transfer the content of div class test1 
and in the textarea should show "Example1" and "Example3".

Any help, please!
javascript or php

john

Answer (score 9):

This would be done pretty easily with jQuery:

```
var newTextVal = "";
$('.text1').each(
    function()
    {
       newTextVal += $(this).text();
    }
);
 $('textarea').val( newTextVal );
```

This above will loop through each element with class "text1" and append it's text node value to the text within the textarea.

Comment: That looks like it could be improved. I would suggest storing the value in a string or array of strings and setting the textarea value only at the end rather than reassigning it each time round the loop.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for pure javascript this would work - though things like this are very easily handled in frameworks like jQuery:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function CopyDivsToTextArea()
        {
            var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
            var textToTransfer = "";
            var pattern = new RegExp("test1");

           for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++)
            {
            if(pattern.test(divs[i].className))
                {
                   textToTransfer += (divs[i].innerText || divs[i].textContent);
                }
             }
         document.getElementById("ta").value = textToTransfer;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="test1" > Example1 </div >
<div class="test2" > Example2 </div >
<div class="test1" > Example3 </div >
<div class="test3" > Example4 </div >
<br />
<textarea id="ta" cols="50" rows="20"></textarea>
<br />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Button" onclick="CopyDivsToTextArea();" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I like the lack of reliance on a library, but there's a brittleness with the `if(divs[i].className == "test1")` line: elements can have multiple CSS classes, so you should test for that with a regular expression or equivalent instead of the simple equality comparison. Also, innerHTML is probably the wrong choice, since you could end up with unwanted HTML mark-up in the textarea. You could use `innerText` / `textContent` instead: `textToTransfer += (divs[i].innerText || divs[i].textContent);`. `innerText` and `textContent` are not quite equivalent but it may be good enough.

Comment: good points Tim, updated the example - just something I threw together, not 100% vetted for all scenarios.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do that by using jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#text").keyup(function(){
    var text = $("#text").val();
    $(".test").html(text);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"></div>
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the "id" attribute for the divs instead of class. Basically, you would need to write a JavaScript function that uses GetElementById() or GetElementByObject().

Then define a button that calls that function passing it the id of the div and the id of the textarea. Finally, set the textarea object's value to the div object's value.

**EDIT:** Here's the function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function copyValues(idFrom, idTo) {
    var objFrom = document.getElementById(idFrom);
    var objTo = document.getElementById(idTo);

    objTo.value = objFrom.value
}
</script>
```

On the event you want it triggered:

```
copyValues("div1", "textarea1");
copyValues("div2", "textarea2");
copyValues("div3", "textarea3");
```

Comment: That would mean a new call to copyValues for every div on the page you wanted to do this with. That could get out of hand fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
function copydivtext(){
   var x = document.getElementsByClassName('test1');

   var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
   textarea.innerHTML = x[0].innerHTML + x[1].innerHTML;
   document.body.appendChild(textarea);
}
copydivtext();
```

Comment: I think this is just enough to transfer the div content to textarea simply without any loops. and created the text area with script.